# `rsync` verbosity using `--files-from`

Tags: rsync

I'm working with `rsync` to archive old files on a running system. Thus, I use a command line of the form:

```
find /some/dir -various -conditions -printf '%P\n' | rsync -v --files-from=- --remove-source-files /some/dir user@archive_host:/archive/dir
```

This functions correctly and does what I want. However, even after passing `-v` to `rsync`, it does not print the files it transfers. I assume this would normally just exclude the command line arguments themselves; however, since the `find` command will produce an arbitrary, long list of files, I would like to be able to see them as the command runs.

How can I see a list of files transferred when using `--files-from`?

Answer (score 0):

`man rsync|grep progress` shows you the parameter `--progress`